# How to execute a sas program using powershell

Tags: powershell, sas

I wish to execute a PC SAS program (`myProgram.sas`) using PowerShell.

I have tried

```bsh
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\DatabaseManager\MGORD\Daily_SAS_LoadingFiles\myProgram.sas"
```

PC SAS opens the file but the code does not execute.  How can I make the SAS program execute?

Comment: Pass the path to the PC SAS executable as the `-FilePath` argument, then pass the path to the `myprogram.sas` file as the `-ArgumentList` argument, perhaps?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run the program file as if it was an executable file instead of running SAS and telling it what program to run.  That is like trying to run a DOC file instead of running WORD and telling it what DOC file to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Start-Process` with a file name will open the file with it's default open operation according to what is installed and configured.  For instance, on my system the program opens into SAS Enterprise Guide.

Consider starting SAS itself and using command line arguments to set system options to do what you want.  The are [over 120 system options](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0rlm7a9issspgn1vj98y6m4q89v.htm) that can be set.

**SYSIN**

Submit program in batch mode.  Creates log file in current folder.

```
Start-Process SAS -ArgumentList "-sysin ""C:\Temp\myProgram.sas"""
```

**INITSTMT**

Submit source code file in interactive mode.

```
Start-Process SAS -ArgumentList "-initstmt '%include ""C:\Temp\myProgram.sas"";'"
```

**INITSTMT** and **DM**

InitStmt can submit a DM string to execute any of the [almost 80 SAS window commands](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n058stj254e9agn17dddil4jddv8.htm). Careful attention to ridiculous quoting needed to perform this from command line.

`FILEOPEN` and `SUBMIT` will open source code file into enhanced editor and submit it.

```
Start-Process SAS -ArgumentList "-initstmt 'dm editor ""fileopen """"C:\Temp\myProgram.sas"""""";dm ""SUBMIT;"";'"
```

**SASOACT**

SASOACT.exe is a helper executable used by SAS context menu items in Windows Explorer.  You can submit source code file from the legacy programmer editor window using SASOACT.

```
Start-Process sasoact.exe -ArgumentList "action=Submit datatype=SASFile filename=""C:\Temp\myProgram.sas"" progid=SAS.Application.940"
```

The commands can be found in the actions installation script, or in the registry.  Submit is located at

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SAS.Program.701\shell\Submit940\command
```

Comment: How could I create the log file in a particular folder?

Comment: Do a `CD` to the folder prior to `start`, or use option `-SASINITIALFOLDER <particular folder>`